# Groovy sh calling docker build is adding newlines to my command

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Hopefully this is a straightforward issue. I have a groovy method I'm calling from within a Jenkinsfile that is supposed to execute a `docker build` shell command. The line is as follows:

```
sh "docker build --build-arg \"VERSION=${tag}\" -t \"${project}:${tag}\" ."
```

However, when I run this from Jenkins, it seems to break this command into newlines, confusing docker:

```
17:26:05.151  docker build --build-arg "VERSION=<tag>
17:26:05.151  " -t "<project>:<tag>
17:26:05.151  " .
17:26:05.451  invalid argument "<project>:<tag>\n" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
17:26:05.451  See 'docker build --help'.
```

The double quotes around the variables were necessary to get the full command in in some form. Without them, the output cuts off, like this:

```
17:17:24.368  ++ docker build --build-arg VERSION=<tag>
17:17:24.368  "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

Something is definitely wrong with how I'm translating bash to groovy, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Seems the `tag` variable contains new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
def tag = "testing_tag\n"
def project="test_proj"

node {

    echo "docker build --build-arg \"VERSION= " + 
         tag + 
         "\" -t \"${project}:" + 
         tag + "\" ."
}
```

Will give you exactly what you have:

```
docker build --build-arg "VERSION=tag
" -t "project:tag
" .
```

You can get rid of any newline characters using `.replace("\n", "" )`

```
def tag = "tag\n"
def project="project"

node {

    echo "docker build --build-arg \"VERSION=" + 
         tag.replace("\n", "" ).trim() + 
         "\" -t \"${project}:" + 
         tag.replace("\n", "" ).trim() + "\" ."
}
```

---

A better option would be replacing **all** newline characters:

```
echo "docker build --build-arg \"VERSION=${tag}\" -t \"${project}:${tag}\" .".replace("\n", "" ).trim()
```

---

Now you just need to substitute `echo` with `sh`

```
def tag = "tag\n"
def project="project"

node {
    def command = "docker build --build-arg \"VERSION=${tag}\" -t \"${project}:${tag}\" .".replace("\n", "" ).trim()
    echo command
    sh command
}
```

This example replaces every newline character, regardless if it's a variable coming from Jenkins (in my case) or not. Just adapt for your needs.